# Uso de la sentencia "Constraint"

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

mi pregunta es que para qué sirve la sentencia "Constraint", es que no logro entenderla del todo, les pongo un ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE persona (
       ID int,
       Nombre varchar(10),
       PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

¿Cuál sería la diferencia a si pongo?

```
CREATE TABLE persona (
       ID int,
       Nombre varchar(10),
       CONSTRAINT PK_ID PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

¿Por qué preferiría usar el Constraint a poner la instrucción directamente?

Sin más que decir un saludo.

Comment: ¿Ya revisaste en la documentación?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si utilizas la palabra clave `CONSTRAINT` obligatoriamente tienes que pasarle un parámetro indicando el nombre de esa restricción. Sin embargo, si no usas `CONSTRAINT`, el motor de base de datos le pone el nombre a la restricción de forma automática.

Una ventaja es que puedes ponerle el nombre que tu quieras, por si luego tienes que hacer algo con esa restricción y así puedas identificarla fácilmente.

Un inconveniente es que ese nombre no puede estar duplicado, por lo que tendrías que tener control de qué nombre le pones para no repetirlo.

Más info:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html#create-table-indexes-keys